# How do I stop the setInterval() function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

How can I stop the interval using the same button I used to start the interval?

```
function slideShow() {
   'use strict';
    var pics = ['IMG_2135.jpg', 'IMG_2125.jpg', 'IMG_2119.jpg', 'IMG_2118.jpg'];
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output = pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)];
    document.getElementById('image').src = output;
} 
button.onclick = function () { setInterval(slideShow, 2000); }
```

Comment: opposite of `setInterval` is [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var interval;    
button.onclick = function () { 
   interval = setInterval(slideShow, 2000); // assigned to a variable
}
```

You definitely need a **`variable`** to be assigned to the `setInterval`, which can be [stopped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) using

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

---

> How can I stop the interval using the same button I used to start the
>   interval?

You do this by setting up a `boolean` check flag like

```
var isRecursiveOn = true;  // by default it will be true
var interval;
    button.onclick = function () {            
       if  (isRecursionOn) {  // check the flag
            isRecursiveOn = false;
            interval = setInterval(slideShow, 2000); // assigned to a variable                
       } else {
           clearInterval(interval);
           isRecursiveOn = true; //reset it
       }       
    }
```